# Fullscreen alignment in TexShop

Tags: texshop

When making beamer slides in TeXShop, I can choose Window --> Fullscreen to display the slides in presentation mode. I want to know if there is a way to change how the slide is aligned when in this mode. The default is that the slide is centered on the screen with grey margins on either side (as in the picture below). Is it possible to align the slide on the left side of the screen?

[image]

A similar thing happens in Adobe Reader (the slide is always centered when in fullscreen mode). So if there is a different program (such as Adobe Reader) where this can be done, then that would be helpful too.

Comment: I think this is a function of the OS (I assume you go into full screen mode by clicking on the green dot in the left hand corner of the window). Every viewer will display things basically the same way. Skim's full screen view makes the grey part smaller than TeXShop's but I don't think you can adjust the centring at all.

Comment: Ok, that seems plausible. I am actually using the "Fullscreen (old version)" option in the Window menu, whereas the green dot seems to activate the "Enter Full Screen" option. But probably this doesn't matter regarding your comment.